# PHP Date time format in SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing my analysis code which will show sales report from 7 from now.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
include 'report/go.php';

$to_time =time();
$to_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$to_time);
$from_time = time()-6*60*60;
$from_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$from_time);


    $sql = "SELECT 
            *
            FROM Tickets
            WHERE LastUpdateTime BETWEEN $from_time and $to_time";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $Date = $row['LastUpdateTime']->format('d/m/Y');
                $Time = $row['LastUpdateTime']->format('H:i:s');
                $Hour = $row['LastUpdateTime']->format('H');
            echo $row['Id']." - ".$Date." - ".$Time." - ".$Hour." Total amount: ".floor($row['TotalAmount'])."<br />";
        }

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

My code doesn't work. I believe I've got some problems with date time convert or that kind of thing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datetime` should be wrapped in `'`s as they are `string`s.

```
"SELECT 
*
FROM Tickets
WHERE LastUpdateTime BETWEEN '$from_time' and '$to_time'"
```

And for calculating the `$from_time` you can do only -

```
$from_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('- 6 HOURS'));
```

instead of

```
$from_time = time()-6*60*60;
$from_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$from_time);
```

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Comment: anthony accept the answer if it worked for you it might help others.

Comment: Sure. I'm waiting every second to accept it. 2 minutes left when I'm typing this comment. LOL